# How can I extract certain content from a txt file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, urllib

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request 
import urllib.parse
x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections? 
from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure')
data = x.read()`enter code here`

saveFile = open('Ergebnis4.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(str(data))
saveFile.close()here
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
{"connections":[{"from":{"prognosis":{"departure":"2018-06- 
07T11:52:00+0200"}}},{"from":{"prognosis":{"departure":"2018-06- 
07T12:22:00+0200"}}},{"from":{"prognosis":{"departure":"2018-06- 
07T12:53:00+0200"}}},{"from":{"prognosis":{"departure":null}}}]}
```

However, I only need the Datetime values without the text.
How could I achieve that?

Comment: That response is JSON, you should look into how to parse JSON responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get that:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")
for item in res.json()['connections']:
    print(item['from']['prognosis']['departure'])
```

Output:

```
2018-06-07T12:22:00+0200
2018-06-07T12:53:00+0200
2018-06-07T13:22:00+0200
None
```

Or using urllib module:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

res = urlopen("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")
for item in json.load(res)['connections']:
    print(item['from']['prognosis']['departure'])
```

Comment: This solution really helped, but do you know if there's a way to do it without importing requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract datetimes from the response with regex.

```
# ...
data = x.read()

dates = re.findall('\d{4}[^+]*\+\d{4}', str(data))
dates = '\n'.join(dates)

saveFile = open('Ergebnis4.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(dates)
saveFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a JSON response. You can use the JSON module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
with open('Ergebnis4.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for i in json.loads(data)["connections"]:
        saveFile.write(i['from']['prognosis']['departure'])
```